# Auto Fill Third party website Form

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cross-domain, html

Here is what I want:
I have one web app (My own) to which I have access to the code. Once user fills in the details and click submit, I want those filled in details to automatically filled in the other website's form(I dont have code access to that site).

I am ready for both the approaches:
 - I-Frame opening in same window then fill in the form(It says cross domain security issue)
 - Fill in the details after redirection.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about cross domain access which is actually not possible.

1. Iframe can just show you page but you can't use jquery on that.
2. If Host is different you can't do that .

If still you want to do then search for Api from site which was called after submission of form.

Maybe that will allow cross domain if thats allowed on server

Comment: Actually what I want is ...When user add details in a form,I want to fill up the details automatically to the other third party site, when user is redirected... Cross domain is not the actual problem, If we have alternatives... So please suggest something on main problem.